# Регистрация пароля с md5

Tags: php

У меня регистрация пароля проходит в формате md5. 
Но при входе в систему :

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$db_name = "";
$tbl_name = "";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($result);
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:game.php?page=pokemons");
$_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo -> id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo -> username;
$_SESSION['level'] = $userinfo -> level;
}

else{
echo "";
}

?>
```

Пароль с md5 не совпадает, подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно подправить.

Comment: вот эту часть password='$password'"; нужно заменить на эту password='md5($password)'";?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";

Давайте сделаем так.
выведите echo $sql; exit;
скопируйте запрос из браузера и запустите его из phpMyAdmin или чем другим вы пользуетесь.
если он не выдаст вам результат - проверьте правильность логина/пароля - так ли на самом деле они занесены в базу.

Comment: Спасибки =)

Comment: а не пашет =)

Comment: У меня точно-точно=)

Comment: Что именно не получается?
сделайте echo md5($password); exit; после получения пароля.
проверьте визуально совпадает ли строка в базе со строкой на экране.

Comment: ага сейчас сделаю =)

Comment: на game.php?page=pokemons  редиректит?
count больше нуля?
код мне видится вот таким:
if($count>0) {
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo -> id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo -> username;
$_SESSION['level'] = $userinfo -> level;
  header("location:game.php?page=pokemons");
exit;
}

Comment: не-а, все равно не работает =(

Comment: запрос в phpMyAdmine запускали? какой-нибудь результат получили?

Answer (score 1):

Дальше этой строчки

```
    mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
```

проходит ?

А то из предыдущих ответов не понятно.

В этом месте и username и password пустые строки (см. не 5 строк выше).

Comment: Проходит за эти строчки!

Comment: Мне кажется, что в username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'"; надо писать `username`=... и `password`= ...

Comment: не-а=) не пашет =)))

Comment: В строке 9 (исходник вопроса) **$tbl_name = "";** 

Может здесь ошибка ?

Comment: нет =) Я уже все пересмотрел..

Comment: Тогда объясните толком, из какой таблицы выбираете, чему равен $count, если он не 0, то распечатайте вывод.

После публикации результатов отладки будем думать дальше. **Внимательно** смотрите, одинаков ли вывод с компьютера и то, что вы набрали в хэш-код.

Answer (score 0):

Оно просто не впускает в систему, пишет неверный логин или пароль !

Comment: Там где $_SESSION['id'] = $userinfo -> id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $userinfo -> username;
$_SESSION['level'] = $userinfo -> level;
}

else{
echo "Неверный логин или пароль";
}

?>